# How to write time and Date format Formula in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal Report 8.5

How to give time and Date format in Crystal Report

```
Time - HH:MM:SS
Date – 2009/08/07
```

Am using VB 6.0 and access database, Date and Time is Separate column, Data type for date and Time column field are memo in my database.

How to write a formula for Date Format and Time Format for the Memo data types fields.

Need Crystal Report Date and Time Format formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a way of parsing the memo field to separate the date and time out, then you can use the DateTime(date, time) function to combine them together into a date time. Then you should be able to use the CSTR or TOTEXT function to put the datetime in the format that you want.

Something like this should work (or be close to working haha)

```
CSTR(DateTime({datefield},{timefield}), "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy")
```

Comment: Make note Date format control characters in crystal reports do not match those used by SQL server or VB6.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way.

Crystal Report Design Window->Right click on the date field->format Field->change the data type format per your requirement.

Works effectively.